# How to give space between words in drawText pdf-lib method in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf

I want to give space between word in my text while I'm creating a PDF document but I do not know how I can do this.

This is my code:

```
firstPage.drawText(`2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5`, {
  x: 274,
  y: 655,
  font: courierBoldFont,
  size: 15,
  color: rgb(0, 0.5, 1),
});
```

I want space between word while adding string into it but I do not know. I want result like this `5   5   5   5   5  5  5`  but string is displaying too close in the PDF like this `55555555555555`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using courier font the inter character spacing should be perfectly even as it is monospaced, just add extra spacing to suit as you have done.

Your code should look spaced out like this, however I suspect your font definition `courierBoldFont,` may be wrong

[image]

Wrong definition of courier bold is not the same large spaces

[image]

I used sample https://jsfiddle.net/Hopding/rxwsc8f5/13/
to test courier behaviour so try your your code and versions of
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.4.0"></script>`
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/downloadjs@1.4.7"></script>`
to replace sample and see if its results differ when using courier

Comment: Thanks @K J for your answer.But i have  also added font like you 
const courierBoldFont = await document.embedFont(StandardFonts.Courier);

Comment: Thanks @K J it's help a lot 
Again thank for your precious answer